# Actionscript: Convert a function from AS3 to AS2

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Need to have the duplicated value from an array, and get the code below that works well but in AS3

Please can someone convert this AS3 code to AS2 ?

```
var array:Array = [1,2,3,4,3];

// create a dictionary and go through our array, pulling out the values
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var len:int         = array.length;
for( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    var val:int = array[i]; // get the value from the array
    if( !( val in dict ) )  // if it's not in our dictionary, create a new array
        dict[val] = [];
    dict[val].push( i );    // add the index of the value to the array
}

// now go through our dictionary, finding the duplications
for( var key:* in dict )
{
    var indicies:Array = dict[key];
    if( indicies.length <= 1 )
        continue; // single value - ignore
    trace( "The value " + key + " is repeated " + indicies.length + " times. Indicies: " + indicies );
}
```

- error code:
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 2 Impossible de charger la classe ou l'interface 'Dictionary'.
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 3    Impossible de charger la classe ou l'interface 'int'.
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 4    Impossible de charger la classe ou l'interface 'int'.
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 6    Impossible de charger la classe ou l'interface 'int'.
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 7    ')' attendu
- Séquence=Séquence 1, layer=Calque 1, frame=1 , ligne 10   '}' inattendu

Comment: yes, the error are in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var array:Array = [1,2,3,4,3];
var obj:Object = new Object();

for( var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
{
   if( obj[ array[i]] === undefined )
   {
        obj[ array[ i ]] = i;
   }
   else trace( "the value " + array[i] + " from location " + obj[ array[ i ]] + " is repeated at location " + i );
}
```

(This is just p-code. I don't have a compiler in front of me.)

What did you want to do with the result?

Comment: Thank you mate, but how to know where in the array the value is repeated ?

Comment: Edited to include reference to repeat location

Comment: the result : the value 3 is repeated at location 4 but it must be repeated at location 2 and 4

Comment: Edited inline again to show 1st position of repeated value

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help mate, How can I get this value ?